# Opening .txt file from URL/URI via browser

Tags: browser, windows-registry, url, notepad, uri

I need some assistance in a project regarding opening a .txt file from URL\URI via browser

I have created below key in the registry:

[reference snap 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnY9c.png)

[reference snap 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOc7T.png)

So now whenever I try to open from my browser, as opentxt:C:\temp\AD_Users.txt, it opens blank new notepad as not the actual file inside with some error:

[reference snap 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Acrqx.png)

One of my colleagues said it's maybe trying to execute C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe opentxt:C:\temp\AD_Users.txt & hence I am getting the error. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: opening a txt file in a browser should simply be a matter of the webserver serving the download with the correct MIME type, and your browser having the correct application associated with that mime type. I'm unclear on where your references to "opentext" are coming from. can you help us understand how that is related?

Comment: @FrankThomas reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594506/using-uri-scheme-to-launch-program-in-notepad

Comment: so where does the c:\temp\AD_Users.txt thing come from? are you downloading the file to c:\temp\ with the name AD_Users.txt, and are then trying to open that document in a 3rd party program called "opentxt"?

Comment: I note that the application in question in your reference link is Notepadd++. I've never seen a uri notation like <applicationname>:c:\\path\to\txtfile.txt

Comment: @FrankThomas I’m trying to invoke AD_Users.txt file located at C:/temp folder using URI in browser. Kindly check ref snaps attached